# Use ModSecurity to rate limit an API with Apache

Tags: apache, mod-security

I tried to rate limit my API with Apache to not have to load my framework and connect to my DB at each calls, but I struggle to do what I want.

I found some examples on how to limit calls by distinct IPs, like below, and it worked great :

```
SecAction id:1,initcol:IP=%{REMOTE_ADDR}
SecAction "id:2,deprecatevar:IP.CALLS_LIMIT=1/10
SecRule IP:CALLS_LIMIT "@gt 1" "id:3,phase:2,pause:300,deny,status:429,setenv:RATELIMITED,skip:1"
SecAction id:4,setvar:IP.CALLS_LIMIT=+1
```

But, what I would be able to do is to group calls by Apache env variable, and not by IP.
So I tried something like :

```
SecAction id:1,initcol:ACTOR=%{env.actor}
SecAction "id:2,deprecatevar:ACTOR.CALLS_LIMIT=1/10
SecRule ACTOR:CALLS_LIMIT "@gt 1" "id:3,phase:2,pause:300,deny,status:429,setenv:RATELIMITED,skip:1"
SecAction id:4,setvar:ACTOR.CALLS_LIMIT=+1
```

But, it doesn't work as in SecRule, it won't recognize actor :

> Error creating rule: Unknown variable: ACTOR

I looked but can't find anyone using a custom var that was set by ModSec in e SecRule.

I also tried things like passing the var to the env, but my env var seems to remain empty ... :/

```
SecAction id:1,initcol:ACTOR=%{env.actor}
SecAction "id:2,deprecatevar:ACTOR.CALLS_LIMIT=1/10,setenv:CALLS_LIMIT=%{ACTOR.CALLS_LIMIT}
SecRule ACTOR:CALLS_LIMIT "@gt 1" "id:3,phase:2,pause:300,deny,status:429,setenv:RATELIMITED,skip:1"
SecAction id:4,setvar:ACTOR.CALLS_LIMIT=+1,setenv:CALLS_LIMIT=%{ACTOR.CALLS_LIMIT}
Header set Test "expr=%{env:CALLS_LIMIT}"
```

So I don't know how to use my custom var in my SecRule.
Does anyone know how I could do it ?

Thanks. ;)